# Does Facetime work over a cellular connection as well as Wifi

Tags: iphone, facetime

Does facetime work over Wifi only, or also over a cellular connection such as 3G?

Answer (score 6):

No, you need to jailbreak your device to [enable](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-enable-the-hidden-facetime-over-3g-feature-in-ios-5/) Facetime over 3G as of iOS 5.

Here's an extract from the [official documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4319#):

> With FaceTime, you can participate in video calls with another iPhone 4 or later, iPad 2, iPod touch (4th generation), or a FaceTime for Mac user **over a Wi-Fi network connection**.