# Does FaceTime take up data or calling minutes when in a Wi-Fi area?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, facetime

I am using FaceTime and calling my friend abroad. I am using an iPod touch, but my friend has an iPhone and is in an area where they have Wi-Fi access.  My question is, does that "call" count toward data or voice minutes, or is it unlimited and free as it's all going over Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4319):

> Check that each person has an active Wi-Fi connection.

Since both parties must use Wi-fi, no cellular data or voice usage will be charged.

More information can be found in this [Apple.SE post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41304/does-facetime-work-over-a-cellular-connection-as-well-as-wifi), as it may be possible to use Facetime over 3G if the phone is jailbroken.

Answer (score 2):

No cellular data is supposed to be used when accessing FaceTime in an area with wifi. But in order to be sure of this it's smart to turn off cellular data in your settings to avoid any fishy usage activity. 
It's located in Settings>General>Celullar.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlimited and free because it is over wifi. Video chat as much as you want for free

Comment: Can you explain this further or cite a source that confirms it?

Comment: @NathanGreenstein http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/iphones_new_facetime_video_calls_are_free.php

Answer (score 1):

Unless they our friend's iPhone is jailbroken to run FaceTime over 3G, the call should be free as it's a WiFi only data connection.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished chatting with Tracfone via their website's Live Chat feature. The rep said, as long as you're at home using your WiFi, it doesn't cost minutes or data. 
I've read online so many different answers regarding this. Some say it's only FREE if using Facetime AUDIO ONLY with your home WiFi. Others say it will cost you DATA if you don't have your DATA turned off when using Facetime and your home WiFi. Still others have said if your DATA is turned off, it will deduct from your minutes even if at your home Wifi. 
So the people posting here on Ask Different are correct. Facetime is totally FREE if using your home WiFi.